# How to change a third order equation to the first order?

Tags: linear-algebra, recursion

I am working on this problem with a third order equation:
$t_{n+2}=3t_{n+1}+t_n-3t_{n-1}$

I am asking to change this to a matrix and honestly I can not quite understand How the change works

Can someone help me a bit?

Comment: it is very hard to understand your equation

Comment: for all n part should be under t I don't know how to present that sorry

Comment: do you mean $t_n+2=3t_n+1+t_n-3t_n-1$?

Comment: (n+2) (n+1) (n) (n-1) all together

Comment: ok, I got it. Use this to improve your latex: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: do you want solve the recurrence or necessarily use a matrix to do that?

Comment: I need to solve it using 3x3 matrix recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

$$x_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+1}\\
t_{n}\\
t_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

and we will try to find a matrix $M$ such that $x_{n+1}=M\cdot x_{n}$. Looking to the recurrence we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+2}\\
t_{n+1}\\
t_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
3&1&-3\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}t_{n+1}\\
t_{n}\\
t_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now you need a initial condition such that $t_0,t_1,t_2$ and then you have $x_0$.

After that you can use that $x_n=M^n\cdot x_0$

Comment: Thank u so much that helps a lot!!

Comment: you are very welcome!